# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Models\\System\\Security' not found in /var/www/html/

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I have been struggling with this error for hours now. I have searched on google and stackoverflow and haven't found an answer yet. I really don't know how to solve it. Apperently it has something to do with the loading of the class and the double backslashes. It's working fine on my development server (mac book pro) but not on the production server (ubuntu server 14.04).

This is how the autoloading class looks like:

```
class AutoLoader {

    public static function autoload($class) {
        $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);

        if (is_readable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/application/{$class}.php")) {
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/application/{$class}.php";
        }
    }
}
spl_autoload_register(array('AutoLoader', 'autoload'));
```

An extract from the Security class:

```
namespace Models\System;

use PDO;
use Models\Library\Database;

class Security {

}
```

When I'm trying to instantiate the Security class with this code:

```
$security = new \Models\System\Security();
```

I'm getting the error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Models\\System\\Security' not found in /var/www/html/...

Has anyone a clue to what I have to do to solve this irritating problem?

Comment: Have you tried printing the path to the class in the autoload function?

Comment: Yes I have. It looks as it should with one regular slash. If the error url had been with one regular slash I would have solved it. I don't know why there is 2 backslashes! I'm also using Slim framework. Could it be a conflict when I'm using two autoloaders?

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thanks everyone how read this question.